# How to create columns dynamic with TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, tablelayoutpanel

I added a TableLayoutPanel into a form, and now I'm trying create columns dynamic to add buttons in this TableLayoutPanel. The problem is that only one column has been created and display only one button.

How could I do this ?

Trying.

```
private void findAllCategorias() {
            IList<CategoriaProduto> _lista = cDAO.findAll();            
            int count = 0;
            foreach (CategoriaProduto x in _lista) {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Name = Convert.ToString(x.id);
                b.Text = x.descricao;
                b.Size = new Size(100,65);
                b.Click += new EventHandler(btnCategoria_Click);
                b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,192);                    
                ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
                tt.SetToolTip(b, Convert.ToString(x.id));
                panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                panel.Controls.Add(b, count++, 0);                
            }
        }
```

**I want this result**

[image]

Comment: `panel.ColumnCount++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `ColumnStyle` is not enough (actually it's optional), you need also to increment the [`ColumnCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columncount(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
// ...
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
panel.ColumnCount++;
panel.Controls.Add(b, count++, 0);                
// ...
```